# Error seen while trying to compile live555 video streaming platform code in Visual Studio 9.0

Tags: c++, visual-studio, makefile, live555

I am trying to compile the video streaming live555 platform code on my system using Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0. The code is available in this link:
http://www.live555.com/liveMedia/public/

I have generated the makefiles for this code using the provided `genWindowsMakefiles` script provided here. The problem I encountered was while running the batch file I created (run.bat). At this stage, I get the following error:

> NMAKE : fatal error U1073: don't know how to make '../groupsock/libgroupsock.lib'

indicating that libgroupsock.lib object file library is not present in this directory. This object file library is not present in the source code either. How do I work around this situation?

Answer (score 0):

The libgroupsock.lib file will be generated by the rule

```
libgroupsock.$(LIB_SUFFIX): $(GROUPSOCK_LIB_OBJS) \
    $(PLATFORM_SPECIFIC_LIB_OBJS)
        $(LIBRARY_LINK)$@ $(LIBRARY_LINK_OPTS) \
                $(GROUPSOCK_LIB_OBJS)
```

from the file groupsock/Makefile.tail which 
genWindowsMakefiles.cmd uses to create the final groupsock/groupsock.mak makefile. I do not know what your `run.bat` contains, but I assume that you should do a

```
cd groupsock
nmake -f groupsock.mak
cd ..
```

first to create the libgroupsock.lib file.